# La statue est (entre/en/sur) la place Tahrir

Tags: vocabulaire, usage, questions

> La statue est (entre/en/sur) la place Tahrir.

Quelle est la  préposition correcte, *entre*, *en* ou *sur* ?

Laquelle est-il le plus logique d'employer ?

Comment: Si je comprends bien, la question est : quelle préposition après *loin* ?

Comment: Cette question n'est pas très claire, le mieux ici est de ne pas mettre de préposition : « La statue est place Tahrir ».

Answer (score 3):

Ce n'est pas une question de logique, c'est une question de connaissance.

*Entre* n'est pas possible. *Entre* est forcément suivie de deux lieux (ou plus) et désigne l'espace délimité par ces lieux. Par exemple, le siège de la Ligue arabe est **entre la place Tahrir et le Nil**.

*En* n'est pas possible. En français moderne, on ne dit pas que quelque chose ou quelqu'un est « *<s>en un lieu</s> ». (Cela se disait autrefois et survit dans quelques cas rares, essentiellement des expression figées.)

« La statue est **sur la place Tahrir** » est correct. On utilise *sur* lorsqu'on considère que la place Tahrir est grande, et que la statue est quelque part sur cette large étendue.

Plus couramment, on dit « la statue est **place Tahrir** », sans préposition. Cela signifie qu'on considère que la place Tahrir est une adresse, un point sur une carte.

À l'échelle du Caire, pour indiquer à quelqu'un où trouver une statue, on dirait « cette statue est place Tahrir ». Si l'on veut être plus précis, on peut dire, par exemple, « cette statue est au nord de la place Tahrir », ou un peu moins précis, « cette statue est sur la place Tahrir, vers le nord ».

Comment: Pas sûr que la dernière proposition soit moins précise car *est au nord de la place Tahir* peut aussi vouloir dire que la statue n'est pas sur la place Tahrir, mais quelque part au-delà, quand on se dirige vers le nord. (ex: *L'Arc de Triomphe se situe au nord-ouest de la place de la Concorde.*)